# How do i setup/enable all the required plugins for kibana on kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, plugins, kibana, connection-timeout

I am using elastic search version 7.9 and trying to set up kibana on my Kubernetes cluster. I have deployed kibana and added nodePort service to access kibana from my browser. I getting a timeout error on the browser. the following is my service and deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: kibana1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5602
      targetPort: 5602
      nodePort: 32343
  type: NodePort
  selector:
      app: kibana1
-----
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana1
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: kibana1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana1
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://192.168.18.35:31200/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5602
```

I found the pod logs in kubernetes dashboard like ways:

```
[2022-02-16T06:48:43.717+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "metricsEntities" is disabled.
[2022-02-16T06:48:43.936+00:00][INFO ][http.server.Preboot] http server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
[2022-02-16T06:48:44.002+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Setting up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]
[2022-02-16T06:48:44.006+00:00][INFO ][preboot] "interactiveSetup" plugin is holding setup: Validating Elasticsearch connection configuration…
[2022-02-16T06:48:44.080+00:00][INFO ][root] Holding setup until preboot stage is completed.
i Kibana has not been configured.
Go to http://0.0.0.0:5601/?code=950751 to get started.
```

Could anyone suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the kibana docker image with the required plugins.

copy the plugin file and using kibana-plugin install the plugin from the given file as given below

```
RUN /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin install file:///kibana-xxxx-plugin.zip
```